# PHP constant as an array

Tags: php, arrays

Is there a possibility to make a group of constants and get them exactly like an array  instead of writing each constant independently ?

**something like**

```
echo MYCONST[0]; or 
echo MYCONST['name'];
```

Comment: Of course it is possible

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you are looking for is called Constant array :

it is now possible to do this with **define()** but only for PHP7
. However you can do this on PHP5.6 by using the **const** keyword and    it is not possible to perform this in lower PHP versions

here is an example :

```
<?php

define('ANIMALS', [
    'dog',
    'cat',
    'bird'
]);

echo ANIMALS[1]; // outputs "cat"

define('MYCONST', [
    'key' => "value"

    ]);

echo MYCONST['key']; // outputs "value"
```

Answer (score 9):

**1.** If you are using **PHP7** , you can define a `constant as an array`.

```
define('MYCONST', array("someValue1","someValue2"));
```

**2.** Version **below PHP7** , you can store a string as a constant, whether it can be `JSON` string or `serialized` string.

```
define('MYCONST', json_encode(array("someValue1","someValue2")));
define('MYCONST', serialize(array("someValue1","someValue2")));
```

For accessing the constant in version **below PHP7** (If it is `JSON` or `serialized` string), you must `json_decode` or `unserialize` respectively.